# Gap between browser screen and menu

Tags: html, css

In my following code everything  is write but it make distance from left right and top of the browser screen.

CSS code is:

```
    ul {
    list-style:none;
    background:#2E94C7;
    padding:10px;
    color:white;
}

body ul li {
    position:relative;
}
ul, li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}
ul li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    background:black;
    margin:10px 0 0 -10px;
}
ul li ul li {
    display:block;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

HTML code is:

```
<ul>
<li>Menu 1
    <ul>
        <li>Menu 1-1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Menu 2
    <ul>
        <li>Menu 2-1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Menu 3</li>
<li>Menu 4</li>
```

Is there any way to cover the top ,left,right of the browser screen.

Comment: Probably just margin or padding from the `<body>`

Comment: add `body { margin:0; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just paste it on your top of the CSS file.

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `width:100%;` is needed here. `ul` elements have `display:block` be default (in this case the default style hasn't changed either), so the declaration will be pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The natural margin on the body tag is causing the spaces. You can also checkout http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ for more reset css related stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The *body* element has margin by default. What you need to do is just override it:

```
body { 
    margin:0; 
}
```

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/DanielLisik/6s3HS/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try a css reset block
so it resets everything that are defaults to the browser

http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if i understand your problem or not but you can try add

```
* {
   margin: 0px;
}
```

to the top of your css.

Comment: This will make *all* elements have that CSS, which is not a very flexible solution.

Comment: right but its at the top of the css which is good for a browser reset

Comment: I've read somewhere it's an expensive selector, but if you don't want the defaul margin settings on elements I guess this is a good solution.

Comment: can you find a link to it being an expensive selector? I have not heard of that before.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors (you can click CTRL+F and type in "*expensive*, it'll be in a beige green box).

Comment: thanks. I didn't know that. Do you know if that is true of modern browsers as the article was written in 2009? Also how do you think it compares to using multiple selectors like body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

Comment: The article was updated Mar 9, 2014, so I guess it's still valid. But with modern browsers *expensive* probably means less time than before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55094/discussion-between-user1964638-and-daniel-lisik).